# minimal path finding using backtracking

Tags: c, backtracking

I am trying to solve my homework and stuck with it , hopfully someone will give a hand .

it goes like this : given a matrix of NxN , every cell [i,j] describes the distance between two cities :the distance from i to j .we are trying to find the shortest route between two given cities - such that we can find shorter routes by other cities : example : from city 1 to 3 : we can find the shortest route by going from 1 to 2 to 0 to 3 . Here's an example :

Please enter road matrix:

0 5 2 2

1 0 1 1

1 2 0 1

1 1 2 0

Please enter source city:

0

Please enter destination city:

1

The shortest path is:

0 3 1

This is what I have so far:

```
/*-------------------------------------------------------------------------
Include files:
--------------------------------------------------------------------------*/

#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdbool.h>



/*=========================================================================
  Constants and definitions:
==========================================================================*/

/* put your #defines and typedefs here*/

#define N 4

void PrintWelcomeMessage();
void PrintSourceCityMessage();
void PrintDestinationCityMessage();
void PrintSpace();
void PrintNumber(int num);
void BestRoute(int Roads[N][N] , int start , int destination);


/*-------------------------------------------------------------------------
  The main program. (describe what your program does here)
 -------------------------------------------------------------------------*/
int main()
{
    int start=0, destination=0, dest=0;
    PrintWelcomeMessage();
    int Roads[N][N]={{0}};
    for(int i=0; i<N; i++)
    {
        for(int j=0; j<N; j++)
        {
            scanf("%d", &dest);
            Roads[i][j]=dest;
        }
    }
    PrintSourceCityMessage();
    scanf("%d",&start);
    PrintDestinationCityMessage();
    scanf("%d",&destination);
    printf("The shortest path is:\n");
    BestRoute(Roads, start, destination);

 return 0;
}




void BestRoute(int Roads[N][N] , int start , int destination, int path[N])
{
  if(start==destination) 
  {
      printf("%d ", start);
      return 0;
  }
  int min=Roads[start][destination];
  int current=0, route=0, chosenR=-1;

  for(int i=0; i<N; i++)
  {
    if(i==start)
        continue;
    current=Roads[start][i];
    Roads[start][i] =-1;
    if(Roads[i][start]==-1)
        continue;
    route=BestRoute(Roads, i, destination);
    if (route+current<min)
    {
        min=route+current;
        chosenR=i;
    }
  }
  if (chosenR!=-1)
    printf("%d ", chosenR);
}

void PrintWelcomeMessage()
{
    printf("Please enter road matrix:\n");
}

void PrintSourceCityMessage()
{
    printf("Please enter source city:\n");
}

void PrintDestinationCityMessage()
{
    printf("Please enter destination city:\n");
}

void PrintSpace() 
{
    printf(" ");
}

void PrintNumber(int num)
{
    printf("%d", num);
}
```

Comment: what have you achieved so far?

Comment: You may want to read this: [How do I ask and answer homework questions?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334822/how-do-i-ask-and-answer-homework-questions)

Comment: This is the exact same homework: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59689774/backtracking-function-is-not-working-as-expected. Pick the answer I already provided. You are supposed to implement dijkstra algorithm to find the shortest path.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [BackTracking function is not working as expected](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59689774/backtracking-function-is-not-working-as-expected)

Comment: @chmike I cant use stdmath so I cant use infinity plus I need to use recursion. Thats why your answer there does not work for me.

Comment: You can define INT_MAX yourself. It’s not a problem. I don’t see in the given problem statement that you must use recursion. If you do, then it’s not the dijkstra algorithm. You have to use the [Floyd-Warshall algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floyd%E2%80%93Warshall_algorithm). I found it in less then 1 minute googling.

Comment: The Floyd-Warshall algorith requires to initialize variables with infinite and thus INT_MAX. Are you sure you can’t include `limits.h` ? This is a strange constrain. Note that "stdmath" does not exist. Only math.h exist.

Comment: I can only use- stdio, stdlib and stdbool